# Typescript switch case confusing compiler

Tags: typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have what looks like a simple situation. I need to send a payload through FCM and I am using typescript to assemble the data:

```
    let msg;
    switch(entity){
        case "dog" : {
            msg = {name : theName, paws : String(after.paws)}
            break;
        }
        default: {
            msg = {name : theName, headType : String(after.headType)}
        }
    }
    const payload = {
        data: msg
    };

    const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload); // error here
```

the compiler keeps insisting that `msg` has three fields and that in either case one of them will be undefined -- either paws or headType -- and that FCM payload does not allow undefined. I just want to assemble a silly json to send to clients without duplicating codes. Is there a secret that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried `let msg: any;` this will basically remove the type errors. Quick and Easy

Comment: Quick and Easy indeed. It works. And thank you!

Comment: Turning off type checking with [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) is indeed *easy*, and if you don't care about type checking, fine.  But the benefit of TypeScript is that you can give `msg` a type like `let msg: {name: string, paws?: string, headType?: string}` and then it will complain if you don't meet that type.  Since the code in this question doesn't seem to constitute a [mcve], however, it's hard to know whether that particular type will be a better fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `type` of `msg`. You can make it like:

```
let msg: any;
```

**OR**

```
let msg: {name: string, paws?: string, headType?: string}
```

The best way to have models in your application so that you can have consistency. You can create a `interface` `Message` as:

**message.interface.ts**

```
export interface Message {
  name: string,
  paws?: string,
  headType?: string
}
```

and then you can define msg variable as:

```
let msg: Message;
```